# fit images with different aspect ratios into multiple rows evenly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Good morning.

First, thanks in advance! I've been a stack overflow spectator for quite a while, and you guys are great.

I am looking to create a photo layout for my webpage www.eden-koru.com, where photos are presented in rows. Due to cropping, and different cameras, each photo may have different aspect ratios and therefor there are many uneven gaps when just placed in a row.

A perfect example of what I want to do is www.flickr.com/childe-roland. Those are my photos, all laid out perfectly despite aspect ratio.

On a different, but similar question I found an 80% solution with this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/martinschaer/aJtdb/:

```
var container_width = $('#container2').width();
var container_width_temp = 0.0; // must be float!
var container_height = 100.0; // random initial container heigth for calculations

$('#container2 img').each(function(){
    var newwidth = (this.width / this.height) * container_height;
    this.width = newwidth;
    $(this).data('width', newwidth); 
    container_width_temp += newwidth;
});

$('#container2 img').each(function(){
    this.width = $(this).data('width') * (container_width / container_width_temp);
});
```

Now, that only works for one row. I have no experience with JQuery, but I was able to see the math and create a "row_counter" variable that counted the number of image wrapper divs... That got me to 90%. I just multiplied the final width by that row count, then subtracted a few pixels to make up for margins.

it looks like this:

```
$('.imageWrapper').each(function(){
    rows +=1;
});
```

My div layout looks like this:

```
<div class="mainWrapper">
    <div class="imageWrapper">
        <img width="326" src="images/_DSC4434.jpg"></img>
        <img width="276" src="images/_DSC4537.jpg"></img>
        <img width="254" src="images/_DSC4483.jpg"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="imageWrapper">
        <img width="276" src="images/_DSC0253.jpg"></img>
        <img width="306" src="images/The_Alaska_RangeIR.jpg"></img>
        <img width="275" src="images/DSC_9111.jpg"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="imageWrapper">
        <img width="276" src="images/_DSC4689.jpg"></img>
        <img width="276" src="images/_DSC4718.jpg"></img>
        <img width="276" src="images/_DSC4738.jpg"></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my CSS like this:

```
.mainWrapper {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  clear: both;
  padding: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.mainWrapper .imageWrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%x;
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}
.mainWrapper .imageWrapper img {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

Now, it looks better than it did, but there is still a lot of unevenness that I can't account for with styling. Additionally I can no longer use `width: 100%` to make my images shrink as the viewport changes.

I hope that I have given enough detail. Please keep in mind that I know nothing about JQuery and haven't touched JavaScript in 5 years. I was an IT major who joined the navy after graduation and never coded again until last week.

Cheers!
Wes

Comment: Why don't you use the Isotope Masonry plugin http://desandro.github.io/masonry/demos/basic-multi-column.html

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm sorry, you are right... I didn't actually use a question mark. I want to fix my code to fit images evenly. Perfectly. How can I do this?

Comment: @San I will certainly take a look. I prefer to do it from scratch so I can learn to code a bit better. But if I become frustrated enough, I will try it... I'm just interested in knocking the rust off of my coding skills and learning new things...

Comment: It's a good thing to code it yourself. But the advantage of plugins are the bug updates.

Comment: So you're asking us to write code for you to automatically fit images into multiple rows and to adapt live to window size changes?  That's a significant project.  That isn't generally how StackOverflow works.  I think you need to break your project down into smaller pieces and ask a smaller question that can be more readily answered here.  Or, you could turn your question into a strategy question where you ask what strategy works well for this type of problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am not asking you to write any code for me. I wrote and scrounged the code together above. Not sure if you noticed that. What I'm asking is for is help figuring out what I have done wrong in what I have already written. I would appreciate the feedback, but if you can't provide help when I have obviously done a lot of legwork and am at my wits end, not to mention very inexperienced, then perhaps you shouldn't reply at all.

Comment: If you look at the way the images line up, there is no way that they have just adjusted the height and width, then have all of the right margins line up perfectly. If you look very carefully at some of the images, you'll note that they have been cropped to fit on the line perfectly (click on the top row, right image, and the clouds on the right are different between the larger and small image).  So you'll have to decide the width of the row, then fix the height, then crop small parts of each image on the right so the numbers add up.

Comment: @TimSPQR Yeah, you're right! Ok, that explains a lot. Thanks!

Comment: You're missing multiple pieces of the algorithm.  You have to figure out how many images you want to put on each row or a more advanced algorithm will even decide which images fit best together on a row.  Then, when you've scaled each image to fit height-wise on the same row and calculated what all the widths add up to, you have to figure out what to do with the remainder you have - whether you crop a few images on the width to make it all fit or add some extra spacing between some images to make it fit.  Then, you need to have resize logic to make it responsive when the window size changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something quite complex. I managed to make a jQuery plugin that almost achieves what you want, I'm having some issues with making it dynamic when a user resizes their browser window, but ignoring this, it should do what you're asking for.

**jQuery Plugin**

```
(function ( $ ) {         
$.fn.gallery = function( options ) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        imgs: [],
        row_height: 300,
        margin: 10
    }, options);

    var container = $(this);

    //create a div for each image
    for(var i=0;i<settings.imgs.length;i++){
        $(this).append("<div class='imgwrapper'></div>");
    }

    //setup the css for the imgwrappers
    $("head").append("<style type='text/css'>.imgwrapper{ float: left; margin-left: "+settings.margin+"px; margin-top: "+settings.margin+"px; height: 261px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; background-size: cover;}</style>")

    //define some global vars
    var imgs_aspect = [];
    var imgs_rows = [0];
    var tot = 0;
    var loaded = 0;

    function setup(){
        var imgs = settings.imgs;
        var row_width = 0;
        $(".imgwrapper").each(function(index){
            var imgwrapper = $(this);
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = imgs[index];
            img.onload = function(){
                //determine the aspect ratio of the image
                var img_aspect = img.height/img.width;
                imgs_aspect.push(img_aspect);
                //work out a rough width for the image
                var w = settings.row_height*img_aspect;
                row_width += w;
                //check if there is still space on this row for another image
                if(row_width >= container.width()){
                    imgs_rows.push(1);
                    row_width = 0;
                }
                else{
                    imgs_rows[imgs_rows.length-1]++;
                }
                //set some of the css vars
                imgwrapper.css("width",w+"px"); 
                imgwrapper.css("height",settings.row_height+"px"); 
                imgwrapper.css("background-image","url("+imgs[index]+")");
                loaded++;
                checkIfLoaded();
            }
        });
    }

    function checkIfLoaded(){
        //make sure all images are loaded
        if(loaded == $(".imgwrapper").length){
            setHeight();
        }
    }

    function setHeight(){
      for(var r=0;r<imgs_rows.length;r++){
        if(r==0){
          var y = 0;
        }
        else{
          var y = 0;
          for(var j=0;j<r;j++){
            y += imgs_rows[j]
          }
        }
        if(imgs_rows[r] == 0){

        }
        else{
          tot = 0;
          for(var i=y;i<(y+imgs_rows[r]);i++){
            tot += imgs_aspect[i];
          }
          //work out optimum height of image to fit perfectly on the row
          var h = ((container.width()-(settings.margin*(imgs_rows[r]+1)))/tot);
          $(".imgwrapper").each(function(index){
            if(index >= y && index < (y+imgs_rows[r])){
                //work out width using height
                var w = h*imgs_aspect[index];
                $(this).css("width",w+"px");
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
    setup();
};

}( jQuery ));
```

**How To Use**

```
var images = ["http://lorempixel.com/300/300",
          "http://lorempixel.com/250/250",
          "http://lorempixel.com/200/200",
          "http://lorempixel.com/210/220",
          "http://lorempixel.com/210/230",
          "http://lorempixel.com/260/230",
          "http://lorempixel.com/410/830",
          "http://lorempixel.com/300/200",
          "http://lorempixel.com/250/250",
          "http://lorempixel.com/200/200",
          "http://lorempixel.com/210/220",
          "http://lorempixel.com/210/230",
          "http://lorempixel.com/260/230",
          "http://lorempixel.com/410/830"];
$(".container").gallery({imgs:images, margin: 0, row_height: 300});
```

*images* is an array which should contain the images url that you wish to use. The container can have any width desired (define in the css). The *margin* value allows you to have a similar white border around the images. Since I saw in your code that you had a row height, this is also implemented, by just changing the *row_height* value.

Demo: http://codepen.io/motorlatitude/pen/iHgCx

This is far from perfect, but it might give you an idea of what you need to do.

Hope it helps!